# Mono shared library under linux location

Tags: c#, linux, mono, linux-native-library

I have a shared library written in C++ that I'd like to use with Mono under Linux,
I follow this guide http://www.mono-project.com/Interop_with_Native_Libraries

I got it to work, but I have to put my library file into /usr/lib or /lib folder.

Is there anyway that I could distribute and use my .so files and not copy them into /usr/lib or /lib but instead into my Mono application folder ? (current directory where the app running)

some user using the software might not have root / admin access, therefore they can't install/copy the files into /usr/lib or /lib

Comment: do you really mean c++? You can't do c++ interop on mono, only C linkage is supported via pinvoke

Comment: the SDK says it is for C++ development, but the library might be written in C, cause the sample code for C++ is calling the library directly (no class instantiation). Link to the SDK http://www.starmicronics.com/support/SDKDocumentation.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have to use the environment variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH when launching your program:

LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. mono yourapp.exe

Comment: well, it works... so I just need to create a shell script to launch the program.

Comment: Or, if you know your install location you could add that folder to LD_LIBRARY_PATH before the library is loaded from within c#

Comment: @IanNorton: is that mean writing to ~/.bashrc ??

Comment: @technomage, no, using System.Environment calls

Comment: @tecnomage : a launcher script is the recommended way to do it, according to http://www.mono-project.com/Guidelines:Application_Deployment#Layout_Recommendation