# embedding mono sample: error while loading shared libraries: libmonoboehm-2.0.so.1

Tags: mono, centos6, embedding

i've installed mono on centos 6 via make && make install from source
when i tried this sample:
https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/samples/embed/teste.c

no error occured during the compilation, but when i run i got this:

```
[root@WOH_Test t01]# gcc -o teste teste.c `pkg-config --cflags --libs mono-2` -lm
[root@WOH_Test t01]# mcs test.cs
[root@WOH_Test t01]# ./teste test.exe
./teste: error while loading shared libraries: libmonoboehm-2.0.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

i can't figure where the problem is, any clue?

Comment: Have you checked to see whether that package is installed and if it is located in the library path,  see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10963498/mono-shared-library-under-linux-location

Comment: it's in /opt/mono/lib/ after make install, but not in /usr/lib64, but system locate this file only in lib64

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. What do you have in `/usr/local/lib`? If you didn't use the `--prefix` option while running `autogen.sh` before the command `make` the libraries should be localed in `/usr/local/lib`. You should see in that directory something like this:

   ```
   me@mypc:/usr/local/lib$ ls -lah libmono-2.0.*
   lrwxrwxrwx. 1 me me 18 dic 19 00:38 libmono-2.0.a -> libmonoboehm-2.0.a
   lrwxrwxrwx. 1 me me 19 dic 19 00:38 libmono-2.0.la -> libmonoboehm-2.0.la
   lrwxrwxrwx. 1 me me 19 dic 19 00:38 libmono-2.0.so -> libmonoboehm-2.0.so
   lrwxrwxrwx. 1 me me 21 dic 19 00:38 libmono-2.0.so.1 -> libmonoboehm-2.0.so.1
   lrwxrwxrwx. 1 me me 25 dic 19 00:38 libmono-2.0.so.1.0.0 -> libmonoboehm-2.0.so.1.0.0
   ```
2. If you can see the above libraries in `/usr/local/lib` your problem is related to where is `ld` searching for libraries. From this question: [CentOS /usr/local/lib system wide $LD_LIBRARY_PATH](https://serverfault.com/questions/372987/centos-usr-local-lib-system-wide-ld-library-path) I guess Centos6 does not have by default configuration for `/usr/local/lib`. If it is your case, just use the provided solutions in that question (any of them) and your program should work fine.

EDIT

From your comment if you want `libmonoboehm-2.0.so.1` in the same path as the `teste` program and you do not want to touch anything else in your Centos6 you could do something like the following:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/path/to/teste/binary
./teste test.exe
```

But I wonder what output do you have when you run this command: `pkg-config --cflags --libs mono-2` (it seems as if you already had a mono installation in your Centos6)

Anyhow, if you can modify your Centos6 the best is this answer: [CentOS /usr/local/lib system wide $LD_LIBRARY_PATH](https://serverfault.com/a/372998). You do that once and you will be able to run any `mono` program without having to mess with the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable. In your case you should do the following:

```
1. Edit /etc/ld.so.conf
2. Write this: /opt/mono/lib
3. Run ldconfig -v as root
4. Your Centos6 is ready to run your mono programs whenever you wish (even if you restart your Centos6 machine)
```

END EDIT

Comment: i compiled mono myself like this<br>
./configure --prefix=/opt/mono
make && make install

it is located in /opt/mono/lib
however when i put libmonoboehm in /usr/lib64, it works
but i dont want to put it there, can i put it together with the teste binary?

Comment: You can, but you need the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable because your library is located in a special path. See my `EDIT` just in case it helps you.